# How do I find parameters declared in a function?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I'm working on the web speech api for my own projects. I'm confused by this function:

```
colors.forEach(function(v, i, a){
  console.log(v, i);
  colorHTML += '<span style="background-color:' + v + ';"> ' + v + ' </span>';
});
```

I understand that v, i & a are parameters, but I can't see where they are declared. They are used in the function and I want to understand how they are used.

Many thanks

Edit: parameters within the parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I find parameters declared in a function?

By reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

> but I can't see where they are declared

They are declared right there in the function expression that creates the function you pass as a callback.

They get values when the function is called.

> ```
> arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])
> ```

So `v` is the current value being looped over, `i` is its index in the array, and `a` is the array itself.

Comment: I see, of course "forEach" is the function! Stupidly that went completely over my head, so didn't look that part up.
Thanks a lot for your help.